# Android (Kotlin) - CookieHandler doesn't work with POST method but with GET works

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I've got two POST methods in my app. One is LoginActivity in which I put CookieHandler(code: `CookieHandler.setDefault(CookieManager())`). After this activity I got some GET methods and cookies are working, but when I want to use another POST method I get `AuthFailurEerror`. Here is my code:

LoginActivity:

```
// this line is in onCreate method
CookieHandler.setDefault(CookieManager())

private fun login2() {

        val req = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                LOGIN_API_URL,
                Response.Listener { response ->
                    Toast.makeText(this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    val user = Intent(this, UserActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(user)

                }, Response.ErrorListener { e ->

            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }) {
            public override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params.put("username", username.text.toString())
                params.put("password", passwd.text.toString())
                return params
            }

            override fun getBodyContentType(): String {
                return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            }
        }
        req.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)

        volleyRequest!!.add(req)

    }
```

SecondActivity

```
private fun aktualizacja2() {

            val req = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    UPDATE_URL,
                    Response.Listener { response ->
                        Toast.makeText(this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


                    }, Response.ErrorListener { e ->

                Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }) {
                public override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                    val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                    params.put("librus_user", usernameEdit.text.toString())
                    params.put("librus_pswd", passwordEdit.text.toString())
                    return params
                }

                override fun getBodyContentType(): String {
                    return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                }

            }
        }
```

Thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: ??? I see no cookies in your code.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I added cookies into onCreate method. Here is code: `CookieHandler.setDefault(CookieManager())`

Comment: I do not see that in the code you posted.

Comment: @greenapps Done

Comment: That does not set any cookie. Only a handler.

Comment: I don't get it, but this code allows user to stay logged and using get methods. So how can I use cookies?